# iTunes Error :- "Folder Name - could not be copied because an error occurred a duplicate file name was specified"

Tags: ios, macos, itunes

When trying to save the documents folder from iTunes File sharing "Save to" option, iTunes gives a error 
 "*Folder Name - could not be copied because an error occurred a duplicate file name was specified*"

There are two songs saved as bellow path

`Folder Name -> Music -> "Artist Name" -> "Album1" -> Song1.mp3`

`Folder Name -> Music -> "Artist Name" -> "Album2" -> Song2.mp3`

I have gone through by downloading complete container and there are no files having same or something like that.

[image: Itunes File sharing]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start | Computer | Right-Click on iPod  | Properties | Tools | Error Checking

Click check button in Error Checking frame.

Problem solved for me.